# Django migrations: merge 'alter table' statements

Tags: mysql, django, database-migration

Suppose I'm adding two columns to a model and alter one more column. Django 1.8 readily generates two `AddField` and one `AlterField` statements in a migration. Then `manage sqlmigrate` shows me three separate `alter table` statements, one for each of these.

I'd like to merge the `alter_specification` clauses of the `alter table` statement, since [MySQL allows it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html). Running an `alter table` three times against a large table is wasteful if one would suffice.

Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: You can write a [custom migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#writing-your-own). But before you do that, 1) how much do you value your own time? and 2) if you get it wrong, how much more wasteful it will be to restore your database from backups?

Comment: @spectras: I value my time, but I also value production's downtime during a migration. Django does a good job determining what to do; I just wonder if there's a known way to optimize the results slightly.